# How to search for all Python packages starting with "truffle" using `pip`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I want to search for all Python packages starting with "truffle" using `pip`.

However, as can be seen below, my searches return quite odd results, only returning packages where the search string matches a complete word. Furthermore, it seems that both `*` (glob) and `.*` (regex) are ignored?

```
nlykkei:~$ pip3 search truffle
truffle (0.1.dev0)  - Code search, documentation aid, code visualizer
nlykkei:~$ pip3 search 'truffle*'
truffle (0.1.dev0)  - Code search, documentation aid, code visualizer
nlykkei:~$ pip3 search 'truffle.*'
truffle (0.1.dev0)  - Code search, documentation aid, code visualizer
nlykkei:~$ pip3 search truffleHog
truffleHog (2.0.99)        - Searches through git repositories for high entropy strings, digging deep into commit history.
django-trufflehog (0.3.0)  - Keep track of creation, update and deletion of models
truffleHogRegexes (0.0.7)  - These regexes power truffleHog.
```

How can I search for "truffle", so that the returned results include?:

```
truffle (0.1.dev0)  - Code search, documentation aid, code visualizer
truffleHog (2.0.99)        - Searches through git repositories for high entropy strings, digging deep into commit history.
django-trufflehog (0.3.0)  - Keep track of creation, update and deletion of models
truffleHogRegexes (0.0.7)  - These regexes power truffleHog.
```

Comment: Why https://pypi.org/search/?q=truffle is not an option?

Answer (score 1):

It seems `query` in `pip search` means "a word"; `pip` doesn't search for any substring but search for an entire word. With a query "ansible" it can find "xxx-ansible-yyy" but with the substring "ansib" it cannot:

```
$ pip search ansib | wc -l
0

$ pip search ansible | wc -l
100
```

I.e. with the query "truffle" you can find any "*-truffle-*" but not "truffleHog". For it you must use "truffleHog" or "trufflehog" (the search is case-insensitive):

```
$ pip search truffleHog | wc -l
3

$ pip search trufflehog | wc -l
3
```

If it's a bug or a misfeature I cannot recognize. [Ask `pip` developers](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues).

*Upd*. Found an open issue: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/6842